# Is there a way to sort the files in a directory in lexicographical order?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to sort the files in the directory in lexicographical order and no matter what I've tried, it still returns is as if I've never sorted it.

```
  def directory(file_input):
 """Returns all files in the directory."""

    files = []
    pathway = Path(file_input)
    for file in pathway.iterdir():
        files.append(file)
    for file in sorted(files):
        search_contents_list.append(file)
        print(file)
```

Comment: I don't see a `return` statement in that function.

Comment: Is the "lexicographic order" that you're after something else than just by ASCII code? Can you give a handful of example file names in your 'correct' order?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` alphabetizes its output by default (on my machine, anyway). If you're still not sure, then you can try `sorted(os.listdir(), key=lambda s:s.lower())` to sort case-insensitively or by whatever criteria you need.